# replacing enum - better solution needed

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have an app that uses React Native' Native Module. 
Currently the logic is that the Data type will be obtained from my enum as shown below

```
export declare enum HKQuantityTypeIdentifier {
    HeartRate = "HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRate"
  }


const requestAuthorization = (
    read: (HKQuantityTypeIdentifier)[],
    write: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier[] = []
  ): Promise<boolean> => {
    const readAuth = read.reduce((obj, cur) => {
      return { ...obj, [cur]: true };
    }, {});
  
    const writeAuth = write.reduce((obj, cur) => {
      return { ...obj, [cur]: true };
    }, {});
  
    return NativeModule.requestAuthorization(writeAuth, readAuth);
  };

  const MyHealthLibrary: ReactNativeHealthkit = {
    requestAuthorization
  }

  export default MyHealthLibrary;
```

Front-end call:

```
await MyHealthLibrary.requestAuthorization([HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.HeartRate]);
```

This will give my expected result

[image]

Now i do not want to call the function from my front-end with the entire type "HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.HeartRate" instead i just want to call it like "HeartRate". Something like below:

```
await MyHealthLibrary.requestAuthorization(["HeartRate"]);
```

How do i achieve this??? Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your issue with enums, but you can easily do that this way then:

```js
export type HKQuantityTypeIdentifier = 'HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRate' | 'HKQuantityTypeIdentifierOtherData';

const requestAuthorization = (
    read: (HKQuantityTypeIdentifier)[],
    write: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier[] = []
  ): Promise<boolean> => {
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to be able to extend your set of values, you could replace the enum by a ts-file that exports constants. It is not state of the art but an alternative.

**TS-File**
my-constants.ts

```
export const HEART_RATE = "HeartRate";
export const CO2 = "CO2";
// and so forth
```

**Your component**

```
import { HEART_RATE, CO2 } from 'my-constants.ts';

// ...

await MyHealthLibrary.requestAuthorization([HEART_RATE]);
```